# What do i and g mean at the end of PCRE regex?

Tags: regex, pcre

I've been working with PCRE regex, and some expressions I saw they finish with *g* or *i* or both *gi*. For example

```
/-([a-z])/gi 
/'/g
```

So my question is what are the meanings of $i$ and $g$ in pcre? I have scanned though the document of pcre but found nothing relevant.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i`, `g` are flags (or mode).

- `i` means Ignore case. `/[a-z]/i` matches both lower case, upper case alphabet character.
- `g` means globals match. Without this flag, some operation matches/replace only once.

See [Regex Tutorial - Turning Modes On and Off for Only Part of The Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

Comment: Can you explain the $g$ flag with this expression `/[(A-Z)]/g`? Thanks

Comment: @Loi.Luu, For example, javascript code `'ABCDEF123'.replace(/[A-Z]/, '')` yield `BCDEF123` (match only once). While `'ABCDEF123'.replace(/[A-Z]/g, '')` yields `123`.

Comment: @Loi.Luu: Your use of `$` characters is confusing, particularly since `$` is a special character in regular expressions. Just surround it with backticks: `g`, `i`.